# How can i delete data store in a file?

Tags: c++, file-io

Delete some specific data present in a file.What ever user want to delete that will be deleted from file in c++

Suppose file contain 5 6 9 10 numbers

I want to delete 9 number which is present in a file

Please give code for it if any one know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the file, and then overwrite it with the data you just read. While overwriting, just make sure that you don't write the "specific" data which you want to delete. That way you'll have a file that wouldn't contain the "specific" data anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file, copy it without the stuff that you want to delete and write it back out.

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file including that unneeded data, delete it from memory and then - write the new data to the entire file.